# How to get current sqlite id for a selected cardview from an arraylist

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, arraylist

I'm trying to use a delete button to remove a specific contact cardview along with it's respective sqlite database entry. I managed to do so by using `deleteOne` method from the `DatabaseHelper`. It works for an int value of the `contactId` that I input (for example 1 in this case)  however I can't figure out how to input the contactID of any desired cardview. since ContactId is an arraylist  which displays all the available elements at once.

This is the delete button

```
            mDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
             //int id= Integer.parseInt(Contact_id.getText.toString());
             int contactId = 1;
             DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
             boolean success = databaseHelper.deleteOne(contactId);
             Toast.makeText(context, "Contact Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

and this is the `deleteOne` method in `DatabaseHelper`.

```
    public boolean deleteOne(int id){
    //if ContactInfo exists, it finds,deletes and returns true.
    //if not found return false.
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String queryString = " DELETE FROM " + CONTACT_LIST + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + " = " + id;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return  false;
    }
}
```

How can I get the correct ID from the `ContactID` arraylist for the desired cardview ?

Would appreciate any assistance in this.

Comment: You should pass IDs to your adapter to get them..

Comment: sorry If I misinterpreted your solution, do you mean passing the id like this ?
 `CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList Contact_id, ArrayList Contact_Name, ArrayList Contact_number,String mLatitude,String mLongitude){
        this.context = context;
        this.Contact_id = Contact_id;
        this.Contact_Name = Contact_Name;
        this.Contact_number = Contact_number;
        this.Latitude= mLatitude;
        this.Longitude=mLongitude;
    }`

Comment: Yes pass the list to the adapter ..